# Rotating a QGraphicsPixmapItem results in extremly low quality texture

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap

I am using a QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView to display a QGraphicsPixmapItem.

Whenever i rotate the item by anything but 90, 180, 270 degree the texture is displayed in extremly low quality. Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwZsA.png) shows the original texture (0° rotation) the [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkElG.png) shows the item rotated by 45°.

I use the following code to display and rotate the item:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("button.png"));
scene->addItem(item);

item->setTransformOriginPoint(70, 70); // button.png is 140px x 140px
item->setRotation(45);
```

Using

```
view->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

or

```
view->setRenderHints(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
```

does not make a difference.

Is there any way to get a higher quality texture  ?

[image: Original]
[image: 45degree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The only way I found to fix this, was to reimplement the QGraphicsItem::paint() and apply the flags QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform to the painter.

Like this:

```
void Rocket::paint(QPainter *painter,
                   const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                   QWidget *widget)
{
  painter->setRenderHints( QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform );
  painter->drawPixmap( boundingRect().topLeft(), myOriginalPixmap );
}
```

Comment: This works for me as well. However, i am not happy with the solution ;)